# Populating Fact Tables(Data Warehouse) and Querying

Tags: psql, data-warehouse, querying, fact-table

I am not sure how to query my fact tables(covid and vaccinations), I populated the dimensions with dummy data, I am supposed to leave the fact tables empty? As far as I know, they would get populated when I write the queries.

I am not sure how to query the tables I have tried different things, but I get an empty result.
Below is a link to the schema.
I want to find out the "TotalDeathsUK"(fact table COVID) for the last year caused by each "Strain"(my strain table has 3 strain in total.

[image: Snowflake Schema Link]

Comment: If you write a *query* (i.e. `select`) it will **not** populate any table, so your empty result is correct. You must use `INSERT` or similar to populate tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html) to poulate your fact table `COVIDFact` :

```
MERGE 
INTO         factcovid 
using        ( 
                    SELECT centerid, 
                           dateid, 
                           patientid, 
                           strainid 
                    FROM   yourstagingfacttable ) AS f 
ON factcovid.centerid = f.centerid AND factcovid.dateid=f.dateid... //the join columns
WHEN matched THEN 
do nothing WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT VALUES 
       ( 
              f.centerid, 
              f.dateid, 
              f.patientid, 
              f.strainid 
       )
```

And for `VaccinationsFact` :

```
MERGE 
INTO         vaccinations 
using        ( 
                    SELECT centerid, 
                           dateid, 
                           patientid, 
                           vaccineid 
                    FROM   yourstagingfacttable ) AS f 
ON factcovid.centerid = f.centerid //join condition(s) 
WHEN matched THEN 
do nothing WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT VALUES 
       ( 
              f.centerid, 
              f.dateid, 
              f.patientid, 
              f.vaccineid 
       )
```

For the `TotalDeathUK` measure :

```
SELECT S.[Name] AS Strain, COUNT(CF.PatientID) AS [Count of Deaths] FROM CovidFact AS CF
    LEFT JOIN Strain AS S ON S.StrainID=CF.StrainID
    LEFT JOIN Time AS T ON CF.DateID=T.DateID
    LEFT JOIN TreatmentCenter AS TR ON TR.CenterID=CF.CenterID
    LEFT JOIN City AS C ON C.CityID = TR.CityID
    WHERE C.Country LIKE 'UK' AND T.Year=2020
    AND Result LIKE 'Death' // you should add a Result column to check if the Patient survived or died
    GROUP BY S.[Name]
```